# .Equals method used by multiple classes

Tags: c#

Say I have code like this:

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Domain
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Presenter
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Say I wanted to use .equals in my test.  Would I have to create a .equals for each class or is there a way of sharing the `.Equals()` method?

I though of creating a superclass that they could all inherit from.  However, the object in the `Presenter` namespace already inherits from a class.

Comment: You could make them implement a common interface and then create an `EqualityComparer<T>` that would work on that interface.

Comment: Please show the superclass that you mentioned and how you inherit it

Comment: An `EqualityComparer<T>` is the best solution for that type of work but May I ask why you create the person three times instead of generating it in a "global" namespace once with an additional field like `organisation/department`. Wouldn't that save overhead and make equals etc more easy to handle?

Answer (score 1):

If it's only used for testing just generate a helper class that compares object to object and try to cast internally to any of the three persons (each).

return false if any object can't be casted to any of the 3 classes.

Answer (score 0):

Note: for the purpose of this Q&A, I am ignoring the broader question as to need. That is, you seem to be duplicating types through different layers of your code, which isn't unusual, but it does seem odd that you would need to implement equality in each layer. Typically, the objects are tied to each other, and the required logic for equality would be at the "business" end of things, with the outcome of equality propagating throughout based on the result in that layer. I will take as granted that there's a real need for your request here, but do at least consider the possibility that you really only need equality in one of the layers.

That said…

The most direct route to doing what you want would be a ["mixin"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). For better or worse, this is not a feature the C# language includes.

It's not clear from your question what the context here is or how you want to use the `Equals()` method. The .NET Framework has a number of different types of equality scenarios, and different ways to address them. But, if what you want is to literally have the `Equals()` method overridden in each type, you will have to actually do that. C# doesn't provide any mechanism to provide a single override implementation across multiple classes. Each class individually needs to be modified.

Note though that you can create a static method somewhere that does the actual equality. You can take advantage of the `dynamic` keyword to allow that method to work with any class that has the necessary properties. For example:

```
namespace Model
{
    public class Person
    {
        public int PersonID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object o)
        {
            return this.PersonEquals(o);
        }
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static bool PersonEquals(this object person1, object person2)
    {
        if (person1.GetType() != person2.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        dynamic d1 = person1, d2 = person2;

        return d1.PersonID == d2.PersonID && d1.Name == d2.Name;
    }
}
```

Then at least the actual implementation exists in only one place. Each individual class just delegates to that.

While I don't recommend it, you can even remove the type comparison, if you would like two objects of different types to compare as equal.

Note that by convention and good practice, you should also override `GetHashCode()` when you override `Equals()`. You can use the same approach as above to do that.

If you do not need for the objects themselves to override `Equals()`, i.e. the only place you care about equality is in a context where you are always able to provide an `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation, then you can use a similar approach, but without any need to modify the original classes. For example:

```
class PersonEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        dynamic d1 = x, d2 = y;

        return d1.PersonID == d2.PersonID && d1.Name == d2.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        dynamic d = obj;

        // ...or whatever your favorite hash code aggregation technique is here
        return d.PersonID.GetHashCode() * 37 + d.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```